# Keeping things RESTful

Tags: rest

New to rest and not having even known what REST was, I began watching a few videos and picked up a book to help guide me towards the correct approach. Unfortunately, my first version is completely botched to hell and I'm likely going to have to break any customers using that implementation shortly. To ensure that I don't need to do this again, I need your assistance!

I have a few DB tables that I'm concerned with here:
'PrimaryBuyer' & 'AllBuyers'
They share a majority of fields, but AllBuyers has a few things Primary does not and vice versa. Each primary buyer is given a unique 'CaseNumber' when entered into the system. This in addition to a 'SequenceNumber' is then used to identify 'AllBuyers'. This CaseNumber is returned to the user of the web service to store for future use. The sequence numbers however are implied based on their location within the XML / JSON.

To specify these tables -> For example, if I were to buy a car I would be the primary buyer and would thusly be entered into BOTH Primary and AllBuyers tables. However, if my credit was bad I could have my spouse cosign on the loan. This would make her a secondary buyer, and she would be entered exclusively into 'AllBuyers' table.

I currently have one REST URI set up as '/buyers/' which mandates that all information for all buyers is entered at once. Similarly if I were to do an update on this URI, the Primary is updated in both tables and any Secondary buyers in the payload would replace previously existing ones.

**Ultimately, there is no way to directly access tables 'PrimaryBuyer' and 'AllBuyers'**

I've been trying to think of a solution around this problem, but have been unable to think of anything that's necessarily RESTful or not a pain for customers. Is it ridiculous to think that the user should (say on an add) POST to /primarybuyer/, take the returned casenumber, and then POST the same information and then some to /allbuyers/? That seems like it would be a little silly on bandwidth among other things. Should things be left in their current state?

Hopefully that's not too much information to answer such a seemingly simple question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it ridiculous to think that the user should (say on an add) POST to
>   /primarybuyer/, take the returned casenumber, and then POST the same
>   information and then some to /allbuyers/?

When you talk about "user" do you mean the person or the system (browser) that uses your service ?

Using a REST service is normally made by a system, today that means a lot browser+Javascript. To do the job for the user person is done at a web facade, and in back is running all your (Javascript) code to make the appropiated REST calls.

Comment: To clarify, this isn't a public web api. We deploy a product to our client and the web service will be used specifically by our clients advertising agencies to dump buyer information into the database for their product.

Our Customer: Hires advertising -> Advertiser: Find's a potential buyer, sends information via whatever program they're using -> WS: Takes information, sends it to our customer's program.

Answer (score 0):

Why not post the buyer's information as a serialized object to the rest server? You could do this via the parameters section of the request. When the request got to the server, you could deserialize the object, and implement the logic of updating the database.

Kind of like how amazon does it? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_AddInstanceGroups.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, so I'll have to do some searching. How I'm understanding this, is it would work much like how it does now. They send a JSON array of Buyer's and they're all dumped into their respective tables.

Comment: I mean, if you place all buyers and primary buyers in the same object, it would be really easy to place them in two different tables, especially with something like hibernate if you are using java.

Answer (score 0):

If the client application does `POST /PrimaryBuyer` there is no reason that the server cannot also copy that case information into the `/AllBuyers` resource and vice versa.